# Using method for scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can i use some method as scope? For ex. i create method which check what params came from json, and then depending on params query some data from database and use as default scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope methods are class methods and should return scope.

You can use procedural scopes since your scope changes based on arguments:

```
scope :colored, lambda { |color| where(:color => color) }
```

and use it like:

```
Product.colored("red")
```

But the problem is Rails doesn't accept procedural scopes as a default scope.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess the problem is, normal methods goes as instance method where as scope methods goes as class methods

```
class MyClass

  def self.klass_method

  end

  def ins_method

  end 

end

Myclass.klass_method => will work
Myclass.ins_method   => will not work
Myclass.new.ins_method  => will work
```

try to make your normal method in to a class method

HTH

Comment: I actually made scope in model and then used it as method with params in my controller